# Android Spinner getting selectedItem Value?

Tags: android, spinner

I have setup Spinner with the layout below, and I wanted to get the value of the item selected, not the displayed text.  Where does one pull out the value?   Also will this work for pulling out values the layout below?  Or do I need some other way to setup (value, displayText) pair? So I guess I need to know how to set it up so it has a value and also how in onItemSelected I would pull the value?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="12dip"> 
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/viewSpin"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
android:entries="@array/some_values" 
android:prompt="@array/some_names"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You resolve the Spinner instance in your activity class with findViewById and set an OnItemSelectedListener on it.  Since you are populating the Spinner with some kind of Adapter, use the items that you constructed the Adapter with and the position of the selected item as reported back in the third parameter of OnItemSelectedListener's onItemSelected method

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html#onItemSelected%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29

Comment: well I was hoping to just initialize it with two arrays one holding display text and the other holding value?  is it possible to do it this way?

Comment: not that I know of.  Spinner can display more complex views than just the default single string per item, so what the Adapters do is wrap various collection of data and views capable of showing them.  For example, you can bind directly to a Cursor, or a simple list of strings (which will probably work for you), or even a 2d collection of strings capable of showing more than just a simple string per row.  The same for ListView as well, as they both derive from AdapterView.  I don't know of any way to get Spinners to report a value for the selected row, so I always resolve a value by position

Comment: The reason for this is i can just put both as string arrays in string.xml or arrays.xml

Comment: Another problem is onItemSelected is called the moment I bring up the spinner. How do I prevent this or detect it is first call?  I've posted another question on this

Comment: I think if you call setAdapter first, which selects item 0 by default after the items are bound, and THEN you set the onItemClickListener this shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will helpful to you.

Try this Code..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Item 1");
        list.add("Item 2");
        list.add("Item 3");
        list.add("Item 4");
        list.add("Item 5");

        final String[] str={"Report 1","Report 2","Report 3","Report 4","Report 5"};

        final Spinner sp1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        final Spinner sp2= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        final Spinner sp3= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp1.setAdapter(adp1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adp2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,str);
        adp2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp2.setAdapter(adp2);
        sp2.setSelection(adp2.getPosition("Report 3"));

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adp3=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
                R.array.str2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adp3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp3.setAdapter(adp3);


        sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int pos1=position;
                String str1=sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), list.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });


        sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int selected_item_position = arg2;
                String selected_item=sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+selected_item_position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selected_item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });


        sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int pos1=position;
                String str1=sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();               




            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });




    }
```